# use C# code in Java

Tags: c#, java

I have a code in C# that I need to use or convert in Java.
It is a code that use a Reference to the Word 12.0 Object Library.

Here the beginning the C# code :

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`

How can I use C# in Java or how can I rewrite the code withe the reference from C# to Java?

Thank you

Comment: You can't write C# in Java or vise versa. They are completely different languages.

Comment: Linq?  Might be quite hard, as Java doesn't have linq.

Answer (score 3):

[Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/):

> The Apache POI Project's mission is to
>   create and maintain Java APIs for
>   manipulating various file formats
>   based upon the Office Open XML
>   standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE
>   2 Compound Document format (OLE2). In
>   short, you can read and write MS Excel
>   files using Java. In addition, you can
>   read and write MS Word and MS
>   PowerPoint files using Java. Apache
>   POI is your Java Excel solution (for
>   Excel 97-2008).

Comment: Apache POI has some problems with docx, xslx and pptx.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the code you can use the converter mentioned by slandau. You can use a number of solutions for Word interop. [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is one. [OpenOffice](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide) is another. [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/) is another.

The good thing about those solutions is you will not need to install Microsoft Word to use them (unlike your existing interop code in C#). You could also use [JACOB and COM](http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jacob/) if you wanted to use MS Word directly.

If you want to keep it simple and use your C# code, you might be better off writing a console application in C# and passing parameters to it using Java (or you can write a web service, [although Word interop in a web service gets tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700726/word-component-in-c)).

Comment: I tried those three library that you motion. The problem with Apache POI is that it don't support pptx, and with OpenOffice I have some problems with the format. And with docx4j, it is the same thing. So I was thinking that using MSOffice, the format will be perfect.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the Java libraries are perfect. You could always crack open the pptx file manually, if you have specific requirements. It is just a zip file with XML in it, so you *could* theoretically manually update it. Otherwise you probably have to go with COM interop or calling your C# code as a console app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool such as http://www.cs2j.com/,

However I would recommend you learn the differences between C# and Java, and re-write the library yourself - or look for a similar one that already exists, PLEASE.

Comment: I think the easiest think is to re-write, but I don't know how to do this the reference.